# Not able to get full data from a column in mysql database using laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am facing a weird problem, I have a table which stores csv format data in it as file_content. I am trying to get the file content in my Laravel application using SQL but that data is breaking up at a certain point. Its returning a partial data only. Size of the data is about 9M.

Table Schema:

```
Field         Type        Collation        Null    Key     Default            
------------  ----------  ---------------  ------  ------  -------- 
id            bigint(15)  (NULL)           NO      PRI     (NULL)
file_id       bigint(15)  (NULL)           YES     MUL     (NULL) 
file_content  longtext    utf8_general_ci  YES             (NULL)
dataTime      timestamp   (NULL)           NO
```

SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT file_content FROM file_data WHERE file_id = {$file_id} ;";
$result = DB::connection('staging_db')->select(DB::raw($sql));
```

When I see the `dd()` of `$result` then the data is less than even half of what should be the result.
Eg. I have almost 37K rows in a `CSV` file which gets imported into this column, but when I am running the above SQL it returns data with only 3.2K rows only in `CSV` format.

**`It does not seems to be a SQL DB problem when I run the same with Basic PHP mysql_connect & mysql_query the result set returns whole data set but when I do the same with laravel then this issue comes back`**

An Ideas on why & how to resolve this?

Comment: What you get for `SELECT file_content FROM file_data WHERE trim(file_id) = {$file_id}`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I am getting `file_content` data but that data is not complete set. Rest the condition is fine, I don't have any issue in that.

Comment: Is the return of your sql always _exactly_ the same if you repeat it? If not there could be any sort of timeout problem.

Comment: @Peh the `result` is always the same. there is no timeout problem also.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the setting in mysql: [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

Comment: `max_allowed_packet` is set to `64M`. So should I increase it?